# How can I know if a mgo session is closed

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm using `*mgo.Session` of MongoDB driver `labix_mgo` for Go, however I don't know if a session is closed. When I use a closed session, a runtime error will be raised. I want to skip the session copy if I know a session is closed.

Answer (score 2):

First, the `mgo` driver you are using: `gopkg.in/mgo.v2` (hosted at https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo) is not maintained anymore. Instead use the community supported fork [`github.com/globalsign/mgo`](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo), it has a backward compatible API.

[`mgo.Session`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Session) does not provide a way to detect if it has been closed (using its [`Session.Close()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Session.Close) method).

But you shouldn't depend on others closing the session you are using. *The same code that obtains a session should be responsible to close it.* Follow this simple principle, and you won't bump into problems of using a closed session.

For instance, if we take a web server as an example, obtain a session using [`Session.Copy()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Session.Copy) (or [`Session.Clone()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Session.Clone)) in the beginning of the request, and close the session (preferably with defer) in the same handler, *in the same function*. And just pass along this session to whoever needs it. They don't have to close it, they mustn't, that's the responsibility of the function that created it.

Comment: mgo provides [Session.Ping](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Session.Ping) to test if connectivity is available in the session.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, but `Ping()` is to check connectivity, and asker wants to detect if `Session.Close()` was called before. It if was, quoting from its doc: _"It's a runtime error to use a session after it has been closed."_ So `Session.Ping()` should (may) also panic.